bilinear interpolation theorem symbol clarification
I am very sorry if i asked a stupid question. I just want clarification for this.
In the book Hajer Bahouri , Jean-Yves Chemin, Raphaël Danchin - Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations, page 10.
(I think this is called the M.Riesz Interpolation Theorem)
Proposition 1.10.: Let $(X_1, \mu_1)$ and $(X_2, \mu_2)$ be two measure spaces. Let $T$ be a continuous bilinear functional on
$
L^{2}(X_1; L^{p_j}(X_2)) \times L^{2}(X_1; L^{q_j}(X_2))
$
for $j \in \{0, 1\}$, where $(p_j, q_j)$ is in $[1, 2]^2$ and such that $p_0 \neq p_1$ and $q_0 \neq q_1$. For any $\theta \in [0, 1]$, the bilinear functional $T$ is then continuous on
$
L^{2}(X_1; L^{p_\theta}(X_2)) \times L^{2}(X_1; L^{q_\theta}(X_2))
$
with
$$
\left( \frac{1}{p_\theta}, \frac{1}{q_\theta} \right) = (1 - \theta) \left( \frac{1}{p_0}, \frac{1}{q_0} \right) + \theta \left( \frac{1}{p_1}, \frac{1}{q_1} \right).
$$.
My question is very simple: what do we mean by $p_\theta$ and $q_\theta$? The confusion here is that because $\theta \in [0, 1]$, then by the notation above we would have $p_{1/2} , q_{\sqrt{2}/2}, ... $ as long as we fulfill the equation above. What does these $p_{1/2} , q_{\sqrt{2}/2}, ... $ mean? Take $p_{1/2}$ for example, is it the value of $p$ when $t=1/2$ (if it is , then this is misleading for me because I confuse this with the usual sequence) or it means something else?
